# How can I compile different groups of sass files seperately?

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I am doing some wordpress development and I am struggling to setup my development environment is a comfortable way.  I am building a parent theme and a child theme.  Each theme has its own set of sass files.  I want to compile the parent themes files only when I make edits to those parent theme stylesheets.  I want to compile the child theme stylesheets only when I make edits to those stylesheets.

I am using live-sass-compiler extension to compile my sass.  I am open to using a different method for compiling, maybe something like Gulp.

Right now, I have split my parent and child into two different workspaces.  I've added my .vscode/settings.json files into each of the parent and child theme folders since they are both the root folder now.

I don't like this setup because I have to use two vscode windows and also vscode can't see all of the functions Wordpress provides via intellisense.

Do you have any recommendations?  Should I setup a gulp task instead to compile my sass?

Comment: Using Gulp would be my recommendation. Something like this [Gulp Sass tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gulp/sass/), could get you on your way, perhaps?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Does this mean it is not possible to configure live-sass-compiler to work in this way?

Comment: Sorry, since I don't use that extension, I couldn't tell you. I used to have a similar setup on Brackets a few years back but with the Gulp setup, you can have more fine-tuning available, more plugins (PostCSS stuff for future syntax usage, etc.).

Comment: Ok thank you. Can u submit an answer?

Comment: make multiple main files, import sass files as per your requirement and you can use node-sass command to compile multiple sass files to multiple css files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you talked about, Gulp is an excellent idea to control your Sass compilation "flow" from start to finish, even conditionally run one pipeline for file `A`, and a different one for file `B`. There are a lot of plugins you can use with PostCSS to future-proof your code, for example.

You can have a look at [this Gulp Sass tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gulp/sass/) to get the hang of it, using npm.